# Converting OData V2 Edm.Decimal value to a locale-dependent decimal number in JS

Tags: internationalization, decimal, odata, sapui5

I'm trying to convert a string number and display it as a decimal number.
For example: `"3125000.000"` → `3,125,000.00`.

In the XML I wrote:

```xml
<Text xmlns="sap.m"
  id="text13"
  text="{
    path: 'Amount',
    type: 'sap.ui.model.odata.type.Decimal',
    constraints: {
      scale: 2
    }
  }"
/>
```

It works well.  How can I display that value from the Controller.js?

It doesn't matter, whether the converted value is of type *string* or *number*. I just want to display that value **with the commas and the `.00`.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [this documentation](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/topic/91f2f2866f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070) answers your question (if I understood it correctly)

From documentation:

> ```js
> var oFormatOptions = {
>   minIntegerDigits: 3,
>   maxIntegerDigits: 5,
>   minFractionDigits: 2,
>   maxFractionDigits: 4
> };
>
> // NumberFormat required from "sap/ui/core/format/NumberFormat"
> var oFloatFormat = NumberFormat.getFloatInstance(oFormatOptions);
> oFloatFormat.format(1.1); // returns 001.10
> oFloatFormat.format(1234.567); // returns 1,234.567
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Property binding with *data type* can be achieved in JS, similar to the XML variant, by assigning the type to `type` but passing the settings in its [constructor](https://sdk.openui5.org/api/sap.ui.model.odata.type.Decimal) function instead:

> Constructor for a primitive type `Edm.Decimal`.
> `new sap.ui.model.odata.type.Decimal(oFormatOptions?, oConstraints?)`

```js
new Text({
  text: {
    path: "Amount",
    type: new ODataDecimalType({ // required from "sap/ui/model/odata/type/Decimal"
      // Optional format options: ...
    }, {
      // Optional constraints:
      scale: 2
    }),
  }
});
```

Here is a demo:

```js
globalThis.onUI5Init = () => sap.ui.require([
  "sap/ui/model/odata/type/Decimal",
  "sap/m/ObjectNumber",
  "sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel", // sample model
  "sap/m/ObjectStatus",
  "sap/ui/core/Configuration",
], (ODataTypeDecimal, ObjectNumber, Model, ObjectStatus, Configuration) => {
  "use strict";

  const oType = new ODataTypeDecimal({}, { scale: 2 });
  const oControl = new ObjectNumber({
    number: {
      path: "/myODataEdmDecimalValue",
      type: oType,
    },
    models: new Model({
      myODataEdmDecimalValue: "3125000.000",
    }),
  }).addStyleClass("sapMObjectNumberLarge sapUiTinyMargin").placeAt("content");
  new ObjectStatus({
    title: "Language / Locale",
    text: Configuration.getLanguage(),
  }).addStyleClass("sapUiTinyMarginBegin").placeAt("content");
});
```

```html
<script id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
  src="https://sdk.openui5.org/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
  data-sap-ui-oninit="onUI5Init"
  data-sap-ui-libs="sap.ui.core,sap.m,sap.ui.layout,sap.ui.unified"
  data-sap-ui-theme="sap_horizon_dark"
  data-sap-ui-async="true"
  data-sap-ui-compatversion="edge"
  data-sap-ui-excludejquerycompat="true"
  data-sap-ui-xx-waitfortheme="init"
></script><body id="content" class="sapUiBody"></body>
```

---

Data types can be also used outside of the property binding independently:

```js
// ODataDecimalType required from "sap/ui/model/odata/type/Decimal"
const myType = new ODataDecimalType({}, { scale: 2 });
myType.formatValue("3125000.000", "string") // returns: "3,125,000.00"
```

[API reference: `sap.ui.model.odata.type.Decimal`](https://sdk.openui5.org/api/sap.ui.model.odata.type.Decimal)

If user's current locale is e.g. `de-DE`, the return value would be then `"3.125.000,00"`.

---

#### Note

- ⚠️ Since [commit `71e40d5`](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/commit/71e40d56dd43b1cd3a1cd8908b23488028ac5efb) (SAPUI5/OpenUI5 1.106+), the `type` instance in static binding is evaluated **only if a model is assigned to the `type` owning control** (either by propagation or by setting the model directly to the control). Without a model, `type` will be ignored.
- The locale is automatically detected by the framework according to user's preference in their browser settings. Cf. *[Identifying the Language Code / Locale](https://ui5.sap.com/#/topic/91f21f176f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070)*. I do **not** recommend hard-coding it unless it's absolutely required.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, It looks good, but when I run it, I get the message in the console:  Uncaught ReferenceError: ODataDecimalType is not defined although I Import  the "sap/ui/model/odata/type/Decimal". Any idea?

Comment: @Ruth You might have missed adding the required module to the list of callback function parameters of `sap.ui.define`/`.require`. I.e. add `MyRequiredModule` to `sap.ui.define(["my/required/Module"], function(MyRequiredModule) { ... })`. See the demo in my answer (Click "Show code snippet").

Comment: Did I forget something ?
 Here is my code: 

 sap.ui.define([
  "./BaseController",
  "sap/ui/model/odata/type/Decimal",
  "sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel",
  "sap/ui/core/ValueState",
  "sap/ui/core/Core",
  "sap/ui/layout/HorizontalLayout",
  "sap/ui/layout/VerticalLayout",
  "sap/m/Dialog",
  "sap/m/DialogType"
 ],

 function (Controller, ODataTypeDecimal, JSONModel, ValueState, Core, HorizontalLayout, VerticalLayout, Dialog, DialogType) {
  "use strict";

  return Controller.extend("deme.FinalProject.controller.App", {............

Comment: @Ruth Yes, you have `ODataTypeDecimal` in your function parameter. In my example, it's `ODataDecimalType`. If you have `ODataTypeDecimal`, you need to call `new ODataTypeDecimal(...)` and not `new ODataDecimalType(...)`. It doesn't actually matter how the parameter is named (It can be also `MyAwesomeType`) **but** you have to use that name consistently.

Comment: Thank you for your help, Finally I use the short way, without any need of the declaration in the sap.ui.define: 
 var oCurrencyFormat = sap.ui.core.format.NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
    var fCurrency = oCurrencyFormat.format(listItemData.Amount);             Thank You !!

Comment: @Ruth Accessing modules via global references (`sap.ui.[...]`) works **only because UI5 needs to support backward compatibility.** The `NumberFormat` should also be declared in the *dependency list* (the array in `sap.ui.define` or `.require`) in order to be detected by the tooling. This enables reducing app size, efficiency, and improved performance when the app is deployed for the end user. If you intend to keep using the `NumberFormat`, please require it too! I updated the other answer accordingly.

Comment: @Ruth The [change is now merged](https://github.com/SAP/openui5-docs/pull/45) into the master branch of the documentation (will be live tomorrow in https://openui5nightly.hana.ondemand.com/topic/91f2f2866f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070). Again, make sure to require `NumberFormat` and to remove globally accessing it (no `sap.ui.core.[...]`).